# Macbook pro M1 with three monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, apple-silicon

I'm using Macbook pro M1 (2021), Ventura 13.4, with three monitors: Lenovo(LEN L24q-30) 2K resolution.

I can set 1280 x 720 HiDPI on two screens only but never on the third one (no option to choose).

I'm using DisplayLink for that, I can set default resolution (2560 x 1440) on the third monitor but I can't see 1280 x 720 HiDPI as the other two. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Can I assume MacBook Pro "M1 Pro" and not a MacBook Pro "M1 Max"?

Comment: hmm not sure what do you mean but system info say 
Macbook Pro 
chip Apple M1 pro

Comment: When you say you’re using DisplayLink, are you implying that the monitors are daisy chained?

Comment: One Monitor via built-in HDMI of the MacBook , second and third via dock station that support DisplayLink 
I had display port to USB-C adapter so I tried to connect the third monitor directly to the Macbook but still no HiDPI showing